# find duplicate data entry in linked list program c

Tags: c, linked-list

I have an `isValid()` function where I want to find duplicate data in my linked list. The function returns `1` when there is duplicate data and `0` if not. But I have difficulty implementing it. Please help me

```
struct Employee{
    char name[20];
    char jobPos[15];
    int grade;
    int age;
    Employee *next;
}*head = NULL, *tail = NULL;

bool isValid(char *name, char *jobPos, int grade, int age) {  
    int count = 0; 
    while (head->next != NULL) { 
        // Starting from the next node 
        struct Employee *ptr = head->next; 
        while (ptr != NULL) { 
            // If some duplicate node is found 
            if (strcmp(head->name,ptr->name)==0&&strcmp(head->jobPos,ptr->jobPos)==0&&head->grade==ptr->grade&&head->age==ptr->age) { 
                count++; 
                break; 
            } 
            ptr = ptr->next; 
        } 

        head = head->next; 
    } 

    // Return the count of duplicate nodes 
    if(count>1){
        return 1;   
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
     
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please don't **tag-bloat**. You might benefit by reading the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You don't need two nested loops in the function: one will do. Set a local variable to the list `head` with `struct Employee *ptr = head` and iterate with that. Also it is not clear whether you want to find *exact* matches for all the fields, or *partial* matches. This implementation uses `&&` for the comparisons, so it will miss a duplicate name with other non-matching values. For that you would need to use `||`.

Comment: Also don't use `head` as an iterator inside `isValid()`. Otherwise, your `head` will not point to the head of the list anymore after returning from `isValid()`.

Answer (score -1):

```
//Create a utility function to compare two Employees - compare
struct Employee* newNode = malloc(sizeof struct Employee);
//Assign values to newNode;
struct Employee* tmp = head;
while(tmp)
{
if(compare(tmp , newNode))
    printf("Copy Found"); // Do whatever you want here.
tmp = tmp->next;      
}
```